# How to remove duplicate words from a string in a Bash script?

Tags: bash

I have a string containing duplicate words, for example:

```
abc, def, abc, def
```

How can I remove the duplicates? The string that I need is:

```
abc, def
```

Comment: are they all comma separated?

Comment: @fedorqui: I changed my string input and run command for editing as last comment. Work fine! 

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have this test file:

```
$ cat file
abc, def, abc, def
```

To remove duplicate words:

```
$ sed -r ':a; s/\b([[:alnum:]]+)\b(.*)\b\1\b/\1\2/g; ta; s/(, )+/, /g; s/, *$//' file
abc, def
```

#### How it works

- `:a`

  This defines a label `a`.
- `s/\b([[:alnum:]]+)\b(.*)\b\1\b/\1\2/g`

  This looks for a duplicated word consisting of alphanumeric characters and removes the second occurrence.
- `ta`

  If the last substitution command resulted in a change, this jumps back to label `a` to try again.

  In this way, the code keeps looking for duplicates until none remain.
- `s/(, )+/, /g; s/, *$//`

  These two substitution commands clean up any left over comma-space combinations.

#### Mac OSX or other BSD System

For Mac OSX or other BSD system, try:

```
sed -E -e ':a' -e 's/\b([[:alnum:]]+)\b(.*)\b\1\b/\1\2/g' -e 'ta' -e 's/(, )+/, /g' -e 's/, *$//' file
```

#### Using a string instead of a file

sed easily handles input either from a file, as shown above, or from a shell string as shown below:

```
$ echo 'ab, cd, cd, ab, ef' | sed -r ':a; s/\b([[:alnum:]]+)\b(.*)\b\1\b/\1\2/g; ta; s/(, )+/, /g; s/, *$//'
ab, cd, ef
```

Comment: On some versions of bash this won't work (eg. `OS X` doesn't have the `-r` option)

Comment: @l'L'l Thanks.  Yes, BSD sed requires `-E`.   I am also told that some BSD systems require each command to be in a separate `-e` string.  I have updated the answer with what is hopefully a BSD-compatible version.

Comment: The linux version you made works (even with consecutive duplicates), however, the `OS X` didn't seem to.

Comment: why a file? The OP has a string in a script, probably defined as `string=something`. `echo "$string" |sed whatever` would be more straight forward..

Comment: @Jahid: whats it matter? `string` or `file` makes no difference, the result should be the same.

Comment: Yeah, but if the OP is new into using pipe/sed he wouldn't know how to make it work with a string instead of a file..

Comment: @Jahid OK.  I added an example of using sed in a pipe.

Comment: @l'L'l  I do not have access to a BSD platform for testing.  If you gave me the full error message or complete output, though, I'll make an effort to debug it.

Comment: @John1024: There's no error on BSD, just that the output doesn't seem to change for whatever reason.

Comment: @l'L'l Thanks.  In that case, my suspicion is that BSD sed does not support `\b` as a word boundary.  I'll look for an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `awk` to do this.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
string="abc, def, abc, def"
string=$(printf '%s\n' "$string" | awk -v RS='[,[:space:]]+' '!a[$0]++{printf "%s%s", $0, RT}')
string="${string%,*}"
echo "$string"
```

Output:

```
abc, def
```

Answer (score 2):

This can also be done in pure Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

string="abc, def, abc, def"

declare -A words

IFS=", "
for w in $string; do
  words+=( [$w]="" )
done

echo ${!words[@]}
```

**Output**

```
def abc
```

**Explanation**

`words` is an associative array (`declare -A words`) and every word is added as
a key to it:

```
words+=( [${w}]="" )
```

(We do not need its value therefore I have taken `""` as value).

The list of unique words is the list of keys (`${!words[@]}`).

There is one caveat thought, the output is not separated by `", "`. (You will
have to iterate again. `IFS` is only used with `${words[*]}` and even than only
the first character of `IFS` is used.)

Answer (score 1):

I have another way for this case. I changed my input string such as below and run command to editing it:

```
#string="abc def abc def"
$ echo "abc def abc def" | xargs -n1 | sort -u | xargs |  sed "s# #, #g"
abc, def
```

Thanks for all support!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with an associative array or xargs and sort in the other examples is, that the words become sorted. My solution only skips words that already have been processed. The associative array *map* keeps this information.

**Bash function**

```
function uniq_words() {

  local string="$1"
  local delimiter=", "  
  local words=""

  declare -A map

  while read -r word; do
    # skip already processed words
    if [ ! -z "${map[$word]}" ]; then
      continue
    fi

    # mark the found word
    map[$word]=1

    # don't add a delimiter, if it is the first word
    if [ -z "$words" ]; then
      words=$word
      continue
    fi

    # add a delimiter and the word
    words="$words$delimiter$word"

  # split the string into lines so that we don't have
  # to overwrite the $IFS system field separator
  done <<< $(sed -e "s/$delimiter/\n/g" <<< "$string")

  echo ${words}
}
```

**Example 1**

```
uniq_words "abc, def, abc, def"
```

Output:

```
abc, def
```

**Example 2**

```
uniq_words "1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0"
```

Output:

```
1, 2, 3, 0
```

**Example with xargs and sort**

In this example, the output is sorted.

```
echo "1 2 3 2 1 0" | xargs -n1 | sort -u | xargs |  sed "s# #, #g"
```

Output:

```
0, 1, 2, 3
```